# find nodes in an arbitrary tree C

Tags: c, tree

I want to find the nodes from an arbitrary tree using a function and to return that node

this is my structure :

```
    typedef struct binary_tree {
    int index;
    struct binary_tree * left;
    struct binary_tree * right;
} binary_tree;
```

and the function i used is

```
binary_tree * search (binary_tree * tree, int index) {
    binary_tree * found = NULL;

    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(tree->index == index)
        return tree;

    found = search(tree->left, index);
    if (found) {
        return found;
    }

    found = search(tree->right, index);
    if (found) {
       return found;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

What i need to modify or correct to find that node?

Or if you can give me another suggestion i would be thankfull !

Comment: Your function has 2 parameters, but you're recursivly calling it with 3 parameters

Comment: sorry, i modified the function header, but i forgot to change the parameters, nevermind, the problem wasn't from there, because in my program i have put correct the params.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use a key (=your `index`) to sort elements and to find them faster.

Your code currently searchs through each element in the tree which is `O(n)`, although it is also possible with `O(log n)`.

The correct solution depends on how you store elements in your tree (how you order the elements).
The following example expects that the left nodes index is smaller than the right ones.

```
binary_tree * search (binary_tree * arbore, int index) {        
    if(arbore == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    if(arbore->index == index){
        return arbore;
    }
    if(arbore->index < index){
        return search (arbore->left, index);
    }else{
        return search (arbore->right, index);
    }
}
```

If (for whatever reason) your tree is not sorted, you need to search everywhere:

```
binary_tree * search (binary_tree * arbore, int index) {        
    if(arbore == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    if(arbore->index == index){
        return arbore;
    }
    binary_tree* result = NULL;

    result = search (arbore->left, index);
    if(result == NULL){
        result = search (arbore->right, index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Furthermore: you should always use brackets. Omitting them only leads to bugs and doesn't have any advantage.

Comment: yes, i see what you did, but my tree is arbitrary, the values aren't smaller to the left and greater to the right :), that was my problem

Comment: @xyz I don't know why you use a tree if it is not sorted, but I updated my answer for that case too.